# Data binding Controller-Service: works for objects but not for numbers

Tags: json, angularjs, data-binding, service, integer

Why are the data synced for the `int` in `json_var` and not for the `int`?

`myService.json_var` is updated when `$scope.json_var` changes.
`myService.int_var` is not updated when `$scope.int_var` changes.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('myService', [
  function() {
     return {
        json_var : {val:17},
        int_var : 36
     }

     }
  ]);


myApp.controller('myCtrl', [ '$scope',  'myService', 
  function ($scope, myService)
  {
     $scope.json_var = myService.json_var; // doing this myService.json_var is updated when $scope.json_var changes
     $scope.int_var = myService.int_var; // no sync for int

     $scope.deb = function()
     {
        console.log($scope.int_var);
        console.log( myService.int_var);

        console.log($scope.json_var.val);
        console.log( myService.json_var.val);
     }
  }
] );
```

https://gist.github.com/SebSept/8ddcaad130ef9c091bd0

Comment: This seems to be the difference between a value type and a reference type.  If you don't want the update then do an `angular.copy(myService.json_var)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, composite types (objects, arrays) are passed by reference (copy of a reference, to be precise), and primitives (strings, numbers, booleans) are passed by value.

`36` is a primitive. 
When you pass your primitive from your service (`myService.int_var`) into your controller (`$scope.int_var`) the `36` is passed by value. When you change `$scope.int_var` to `42` the `myService.int_var` variable will not reflect the change (this is per language design).

On the other hand, `myService.json_var` is a composite. When you pass `myService.json_var` to `$scope.json_var`, a reference to the `myService.json_var` object is passed by value to the `$scope.json_var` variable. When you change something inside that variable (e.g. if you change `json_var.val` to `18`), the change will be reflected inside the `myService.json_var` object as well, so `myService.json_var.val` will equal `18` as well.

**tl;dr** Make sure there's always a dot "." somewhere when you're passing things around in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers aren't mutable. Binding to numbers sucks, cause as soon as the number changes, you lost reference what you are bound, as the reference to the old number is lost (to you). If you are going to reference numbers that will be changing, you have to place them in an object and then bind to the object (cause objects are mutable).

When learning Angular, I ran into this same frustration. I think that a lot of people do.